# How to create JButtons using JMenuItem and ActionListener

Tags: java, jbutton, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I am attempting to create JButtons through the use of a JMenuItem. I have a New Employee JMenuItem which when clicked opens up a frame with four JTextFields: Employee Name, Employee IDNumber, Employee Pay Rate, and Employee Hours Worked, and one JButton, Apply. After the user inputs the data into the JTextFields and hits the Apply JButton, the main window is supposed to add a JButton with the inputted data.

Here is the code for the Program Display

```
 public ProgramDisplay() {

        setTitle("Fluid Accounts");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        account = new JButton("<html>" + "Samuel Tayman" + "<br>" + "Wages: " + findPay(hours, payRate));
        add(account);
        account = new JButton("<html>" + "Janice" + "<br>" + "Wages: " + findPay(hours, payRate));
        add(account);

        buildMenuBar();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
```

And here is the code for the New Employee `JMenuItem` with the `ActionListener`:

```
private void buildEmployeeMenu()

{

    newEmployee = new JMenuItem("New Employee");
    newEmployee.addActionListener(new NewListener());
    employeeMenu = new JMenu("Employees");
    employeeMenu.add(newEmployee);

}

/**
 * Private inner class that handles the event that is generated when the
 * user selects New from the file menu.
 */

private class NewListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        name = "";
        employeeID = "";
        rateOfPay = "";
        hoursWorked = "";
        JButton Apply = new JButton("Apply");

        Apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                name = nameField.getText();
                employeeID = IDField.getText();
                rateOfPay = payRateField.getText();
                hoursWorked = hoursField.getText();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        add(nameField = new JTextField("Enter the Employee Name"));
        add(IDField = new JTextField("Enter the Employee's ID Number"));
        add(payRateField = new JTextField("Enter the Employee's Pay Rate"));
        add(hoursField = new JTextField("Enter the Employee's Hours Worked"));
        add(Apply);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

[Example of current running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdyiO.png)

I've made it so that the data stored in the `textField` components are saved into fields however I haven't been able to successfully create a `JButton` in the main program window using the Apply button.

Any help and assistance is appreciated!

Comment: your Program Display JFrame will have to know about the text inside the JText fields in the NewListener otherwise it won't be able to extract the newly entered text.

Comment: Once the Program Display knows what name, employeeID ect. are, you'll need to grab the button in question and then change the button's attributes according to the name, employeeID ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a method to add a JButton in the ProgramDisplay class, e.g.

```
 void addButton(String name, String employeeID, String rateOfPay, String hoursWorked) {
      add(new JButton(name + ":" + employeeID + ", " + rateOfPay + " - " + hoursWorked); }
```

pass the ProgramDisplay instance as final parameter to the NewListener, e. g.

```
private class NewListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
     final ProgramDisplay pd;
     NewListener(ProgramDisplay pd) {
          this.pd = pd;
     }  
 .....
```

and call the addButton method from within your ActionPerformed method:

```
    Apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            name = nameField.getText();
            employeeID = IDField.getText();
            rateOfPay = payRateField.getText();
            hoursWorked = hoursField.getText();
            setVisible(false);
            NewListener.this.pd.addButton(name, employeeID, rateOfPay, hoursWorked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't think about making another method for it, I kept working on the Apply button's ActionListener instead. After a few small changes to fit the rest of the code, the buttons are being added successfully with the data inputted. Running across a few more problems, but I believe enough research with trial and error will help get me where I need to be. I appreciate the help!